# How to get PHP variable from JS AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I make an AJAX request:

```
//javascript
var rq = new XMLHTTPrequest();
rq.open('POST','test.php', true);
rq.send(JSONString);
```

In "test.php" I make something like:

```
//php
$data = "Hello";
```

And I want to return $data back to my JS (via rq.responseText I suppose) how should I do it?

Comment: try `echo "Hello"` in PHP

Comment: doesnt work, I get an empty string

Comment: where do you get an empty string? nowhere in your code do you deal with the response

Comment: alert(rq.response);

Comment: huh? a) that's not in the code you posted and b) that shows one problem you have is not knowing how XHR even works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dammit, the problem was that I did

```
rq.onload = alert(rq.response);
```

Instead of

```
rq.onload = function()
{
  alert(rq.response);
}
```

Sorry pals

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest.response` to get the response.

Please see the following code snippet and check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response) for details.

```js
var url = 'test.php'; //A local page

function load(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      callback(xhr.response);
    }
  }

  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.send(JSONString);
}
```

Comment: But how do I get the value of $data? My rq.response is empty.

Comment: @Dinoabunai - what http server are you using (apache, nginx, something else)? and what version of PHP is installed in your server?

Answer (score 0):

You can return JSON from PHP. EX
in javascript:

```
$.ajax({
   url         : url_api,
   method      : 'GET',
   dataType    : 'json',
   data        : {},
   success     : function (data) {          
       var hello = data.data;
   }
 });
```

In PHP:

```
<?php
$array = ['data' => 'hello'];
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Can I make it without JQuery?

Comment: yes of course you can do it without jquery - jquery is just a library for lazy coders